# How to navigate long formulas with the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, conditional-formatting

One way I commonly use conditional formatting is to highlight whether two cells are equal.

Example (Excel 2016):

[image: Excel spreadsheet sample with differently highlighted matching and non-matching cells]

Is cell F14 both (1) not blank and (2) equal in value to cell C14? TRUE: Fill green. FALSE: Fill red.

When entering this in the conditional formatting window, the formula ends up being something like:

`=AND(NOT(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-11))=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))`

And that's just for the green format. I'll have to do the same for the red format, just with `<>` instead of `=`.

(This formula doesn't work, by the way. Hence my need for easy editing while debugging.)

The problem is that the text box for entering such a long formula is very small, making it difficult to edit the formula.

[image: Screenshot of Edit Formatting Rule window]

What makes it especially difficult is the fact that I cannot jump around within the formula text by using keys like "End" and the arrow keys, as I normally would. Since there's no way to resize the window, I have to use the mouse to click and drag just beyond the end of that little text box so it scrolls to the right until I've highlighted up to where I want to make edits. And the scroll speed using this method is *very sensitive*! If I try using the arrow keys, Excel thinks I want to navigate the sheet to select some cells for the formula.

I've tried using the arrow keys while holding down Ctrl, Shift, Alt, or any combination of those. To no avail.

One workaround I've used is typing the formula into the worksheet first and then copy/pasting it into the Edit Formatting Rule window. The only problem is if you want to see a meaningful value in the worksheet to make sure your formula works, you end up having to change cell references when you paste it. And then it's back to highlighted text scrolling.

This is aggravating. **Is there a way to move through the formula using the keyboard?**

---

Not necessarily related to the question title, but would help the problem:

- Is there an easier way to specify "this cell", instead of `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))`? That would at least shorten the formula.
- Why doesn't my formula work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move through the formula using the keyboard, select anywhere in the formula and hit the F2 key.

This is the same functionality as when editing a formula in a cell.  If you just use the arrow keys, it will select cells for use in the formula.  If you are selected in a formula and hit F2, it will switch so that the arrow keys move the cursor through the formula.

After hitting F2, holding down the shift and control keys also offers similar functionality for snapping to the end of a word and highlighting text.

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need two conditions:

The first one (for green) uses the following formula:

```
=AND(F14<>"",F14=C14)
```

And the second one (for red) uses:

```
=AND(F14<>"",F14<>C14)
```

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad. But it seems that only the first cell is filled when I use this. For example, if I apply the formula to the range $F$11:$F$23 (assuming all other cells in the worksheet are blank), only F11 is green. I would expect only F14 to be green. How do we get the same kind of relative references in conditional formatting that we use in cell formulas? This is why I've been using `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))`.

Comment: Whatever the first row you apply it to is the row you want in the formulas for the conditions. i.e. if you apply it on `F11:F23` you should use `=AND(F11<>"",F11=C11)`. I based myself on your screencap

Comment: Got it, thanks! Two valuable insights here: How to use relative references in a conditional formatting formula and a shorter way of doing "not blank". Very helpful!